# CRUD for joinned view with LINQ to SQL class C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, crud

Here comes some background for my problem:

1. I have a Strongly-Typed view in my application, to display a list.
2. Once the information I want to show comes from different tables I had to do some joins in my LINQ query, and for this reason I had to create a custom model.
3. Now I want to realize CRUD operations using the ID of the rows of my list.

**The model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace LMWEB_MVC.Models
{
    public class LeaseViewModel
    {
        [Key] public int Lease_Detail_ID { get; set; }
        public string Lease_ID { get; set; }
        public string XRef_Lease_ID { get; set; }
        public string Vendor_Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Payment_Due_Date { get; set; }
        public short Authorized { get; set; }
        public string Line_Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeasesContext : DbContext
    {
        public LeasesContext()
            : base("LMWEBConnectionString1")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Models.LeasesContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<LeaseViewModel> LeaseViewModels { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**The view**

```
@model IEnumerable<LMWEB_MVC.Models.LeaseViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Leases";
}

<link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h2>Leases</h2>
<div>

</div>
<div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
</div>
<div style="scrollbar-base-color: #eeeeee; background: white; position: relative; border-right: black 1px solid;
border-top: black 1px solid; overflow-y: scroll; border-left: black 1px solid; border-bottom: black 1px solid;
height: 650px; width:100%; border-spacing: 10px 10px">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 65px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lease_ID)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 75px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.XRef_Lease_ID)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 85px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vendor_Name)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 185px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 85px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 85px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 60px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payment_Due_Date)
            </th>
            @*<th style="width: 70px;" class="head">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Authorized)
                </th>*@
            <th style="width: 70px;" class="head">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Line_Type)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20px;" class="head"></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 65px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lease_ID)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 75px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.XRef_Lease_ID)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 85px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vendor_Name)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 185px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 85px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 85px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 60px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payment_Due_Date)
                </td>
                @*<td class="leasegrid">
                           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Authorized)
                    </td>*@
                <td style="width: 70px;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Line_Type)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 140px;" class="leasegrid">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { item.Lease_Detail_ID }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { item.Lease_Detail_ID }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.Lease_Detail_ID }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

**The controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LMWEB_MVC.Models;

namespace LMWEB_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class LeasesController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Leases()
        {
            LMWEBLINQDataContext leases = new LMWEBLINQDataContext();
            var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                             join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID
                             join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID
                             join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID
                             join t in leases.tblvLineTypes on l.Line_Type_ID equals t.Line_Type_ID
                             select new
                             {
                                 l.Lease_Detail_ID,
                                 l.Lease_ID,
                                 l.XRef_Lease_ID,
                                 v.Vendor_Name,
                                 l.Description,
                                 c.County,
                                 l.Amount,
                                 l.Payment_Due_Date,
                                 a.Authorized,
                                 t.Line_Type
                             }).Distinct().ToList().ToNonAnonymousList(new List<LeaseViewModel>()).Take(10);

            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            return View(leaseList);
        }

        private LeasesContext db = new LeasesContext();

        //
        // GET: /Leases/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.LeaseViewModels.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Leases/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int Lease_Detail_ID = 0)
        {
            LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel = db.LeaseViewModels.Find(Lease_Detail_ID);
            if (leaseviewmodel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(leaseviewmodel);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Leases/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Leases/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.LeaseViewModels.Add(leaseviewmodel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(leaseviewmodel);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Leases/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int Lease_Detail_ID = 0)
        {
            LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel = db.LeaseViewModels.Find(Lease_Detail_ID);
            if (leaseviewmodel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(leaseviewmodel);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Leases/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(leaseviewmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(leaseviewmodel);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Leases/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int Lease_Detail_ID = 0)
        {
            LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel = db.LeaseViewModels.Find(Lease_Detail_ID);
            if (leaseviewmodel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(leaseviewmodel);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Leases/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int Lease_Detail_ID)
        {
            LeaseViewModel leaseviewmodel = db.LeaseViewModels.Find(Lease_Detail_ID);
            db.LeaseViewModels.Remove(leaseviewmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**The error I receive**

An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

**The inner exception**

{"Invalid object name 'dbo.LeaseViewModels'."}

**And finally *(thanks for reaching this point)* my question:**

I understand that none of my CRUD operations are getting completed because there is no dbo.LeaseViewModels in my database. LeaseViewModels is just a model that I created to store my joined query. So here is my doubt: **how do I do to realize CRUD operations in my database, starting from this custom view? Is it possible? In case it isn't, how can I create a view with information coming from different tables if not with a custom model?**

**Note:** I don't have DBO access to my database. I have access only to read and execute procedures.

Comment: Create the tables first. Either run a script to create them, or yse Entity Framework Migrations. The exception is an Entity Framework exception, not LINQ-to-SQL. Other than that, check an Entity Framework tutorial or a course in Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Panagiotis! I just added a note, informing that I don't have full access to my DB. That made me realize that my controllers should be trying to run my procedures, am I right?
I tried to use Entity Framework, but I received a NuGet error, and ended up using LINQ-to-SQL. Is that possible that there are any leftover codes from when I created the Entity Framework model?

Comment: If you get a NuGet error, fix the nuget error. Don't throw away the primary .NET ORM because you thought it was broken. Again, I advice you take a tutorial or a course. This is far too basic stuff, you can't create an application if you don't realize you are fully using EF, not just some leftover code

Comment: Unfortunately taking a course is not an option, that's why I'm seeking for help here. But I'll definitely look for some tutorials. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your DbContext. 
The DbContext class should map the database tables to domain classes of your application.

Remove the LeaseViewModel from the DbContext and add the tables of the database (Vendor and Country, for example). Then you can use a linq expression to join tables and return a LeaseViewModel object for your view.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

I'm adding some links about EF mappings that may help you:

- Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx
- Database first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx
- Code first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alexandre! I created all the tables in my DbContext with a code like this *public DbSet<tblvVendor> tblvVendors { get; set; }* for each table, and deleted the LeaseViewModel as you suggested. It led to a problem in my controllers in all CRUD methods, once *db.LeaseViewModels.Find(Lease_Detail_ID);* can't be accessed anymore. I thought about creating the controller again, this time using the new/fixed context as reference, but this led to a dataModel error, because my primary keys aren't properly set in the db. I'll fix it and let you know if it works. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Check the mappings of your domain classes, they should match the database schema otherwise Entity Framework will throw an exception. I updated my answer with some links about EF mappings.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have created your DbContext class, it's looking for a single table called LeaseViewModel. If you can't create that table, you need to change your DbContext to actually hold DbSets to tblfLeaseDetails, tblvVendors , tblvCounties etc. Then in the controller (or better yet in some DAL module), you can use a join similar to yours to create your viewmodel and then use that viewmodel in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Harsh! **1st:** I have all those tables set in my LINQ.designer.cs file (they were all automatically created when I created my LINQ-to-SQL class), but when I try to create the Strongly-Typed controller with my LINQ context it says that the context is unsuspected, that's why I used the context in my model in order to create the controller. Should I just copy the models form the LINQ designer file? Are these definitions the same? **2nd:** I am supposed to declare my custom model inside the controller?